# How to calculate this Riemann-Stieltjes integral?

Tags: integration, riemann-integration, stieltjes-integral

How to calculate this Riemann-Stieltjes integral?

\begin{equation}
\int_{1}^{3}e^{x}d\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor 
\end{equation}

If $x\in\left[0,\,3\right]$, then $\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor =I\left(x-1\right)+I\left(x-2\right)+I\left(x-3\right)$,
where $I\left(x-a_{i}\right)=0$ if $x<a_{i}$, $I\left(x-a_{i}\right)=1$
if $x\geq a_{i}$.

Then it is easy, we have $\int_{0}^{3}e^{x}d\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor =\sum_{n=1}^{3}e^{a_{i}}$.

But here $x\in\left[1,\,3\right]$, so how to deal with it ? Thank
you very much.

Comment: Try writing the Riemann-Stieltjes sums.

Answer (score 2):

Let
$$f(x) = e^x, \;g(x) = \lfloor x \rfloor, \\
I = \int_1^3 f(x) dg(x).$$
If you have a formula to compute $F(x) = \int_0^x f(t) dg(t)$, then $I = F(3) - F(1)$.

Alternatively,
$$I =
f(2) \lim_{\epsilon \downarrow 0} (g(2 + \epsilon) - g(2 - \epsilon)) +
 f(3) \lim_{\epsilon \downarrow 0} (g(3) - g(3 - \epsilon)).$$

As another option,
$$I = f(3) g(3) - f(1) g(1) - \int_1^3 f'(x) g(x) dx.$$

Comment: How you came up with the other option?

Comment: The last formula is obtained by applying [integration by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral#Properties) and using the fact that $f \in C^1(\mathbb R)$.

Answer (score 0):

I'm about five years late to this one, but since it's still unanswered I figured I might as well post an answer to it anyways.

So in general, it's the case that
$$\int_1^nf(x)\ d \left \lfloor x \right \rfloor = \sum _{k=2} ^n f(k).$$
Applying this identity here gives that
$$\int _1 ^3 e^x \ d \left \lfloor x \right \rfloor = \sum_{k = 2} ^3e^k = e^2 + e^3.$$
To prove the above identity, I would suggest (as a small hint) splitting the function $\left \lfloor x \right \rfloor$ into three step functions.